# Kernel mapping from feature space to input space

Tags: linear-transformations, svd

My linear algebra foundation is really weak, so please bear with me. I am working with a vector and a kernel matrix. The kernel matrix is 500x500, call it *K*, and the input is a 500x1 vector, call it *a*.

I can calculate the 500x1 vector, *t*, by multiplying the kernel with the input:
*t* = *Ka*. Now, suppose I'm given only *K* and *t*. I'm attempting to use those to find *a*. I suppose to put it another way, if *K* maps *a* from the input space to the feature space containing *t*, I am trying to find another kernel matrix such that you map *t* back to the input space.

At first, I thought of finding the inverse of the kernel matrix, but I can't get the inverse of the kernel matrix in MATLAB. I think it might be because the upper right half of the kernel matrix is triangular, filled with all 0s. 
I then thought that I could break down the matrix into two smaller matrices with non-negative matrix factorization (NNMF), but that didn't work out at all with MATLAB. Precision was off, and when I multiplied the two resulting matrices back to approximate the original kernel, it showed 'INF' for all entries.

Right now, I used SVD to get the singular values of the kernel, and using U,S,V (again, MATLAB), I got the inverse of the kernel matrix. However, when I multiplied *K inverse* with *t*, the result did not 100% match up with *t*. I'd say that the first 300 entries were really close to each other with the remaining 200 entries being wildly off by a large magnitude.

I know that this is a really vague description, but my knowledge of linear algebra is very weak, and I'm not sure what else I can do. Is there a way to map from the feature space to the input space? Is SVD the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Being unable to look at the data, we can offer only a hunch.

You start with a matrix $\mathbf{K}\in\mathbb{R}^{500\times5000}$ and a vector $t\in\mathbb{R}^{500}$. You propose the model 
$$
 \mathbf{K} a = t
$$
and you wish to solve for the solution vector $t\in\mathbb{R}^{500}$. You compute the singular value decomposition 
$$
\mathbf{K} = \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$
and form the Moore-Penrose pseudoscience via 
$$
\mathbf{K}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{\dagger} \, \mathbf{U}^{*}.
$$
You are unhappy with
$$
 \lVert a - \mathbf{K}^{\dagger} t \rVert.
$$

**Educated guess**

Your problem is ill-conditioned.

Compute the matrix condition number by
$$
 \kappa_{2} = \lVert \mathbf{A}^{-1} \rVert_{2} \lVert \mathbf{A} \rVert_{2} =\frac{\sigma_{1}} {\sigma_{500}}
$$

Threshold your singular values; set the lowest terms to 0. Retain only the first $k$ singular values.

For illustration, examine the 256 $\times$ 256 matrix below, an image, and the spectrum of singular values plotted on the right. For instance, you may decide that if the singular value is less than $10^{-10}$ it will be set to $0$.

[image: Camille spectrum]

It sounds like your singular values suffer the common malady of being a small number instead of $0$.