# Matlab code to compute the smallest nonzero singular value of the matrix without using SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, singular-values

I want to compute the smallest nonzero singular value of the matrix A, which is defined as follows.

Let $B =  rand(500, 250)$, $A = B*B^t$, where $t$ denotes the transpose of the matrix.

I found the following matlab code to compute singular values of the matrix A which is based on the Singular value decomposition of the matrix.

```
svds = svd(A);                             
s = min(svds);  % smallest singular value
```

I want to know is there any other efficient way to smallest singular value?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your code does not compute the smallest positive singular value, since svds() returns only the six largest singular values. see here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svds.html

Comment: I do not have time now for more details, but it is possible in the svd iterations to concentrate only on the smallest singular value. That would allow for Householder rotations since the other values get ignored. I imagine it would be faster than a full svd. Tonight or tomorrow I can type up details if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A=BB^T$, it is symmetric and positive semidefinite, and its singular values are identical to its eigenvalues. Furthermore, its nonzero eigenvalues are identical to the nonzero eigenvalues of $B^TB$. To get the smallest eigenvalue of $B^TB$, use `eigs(B'*B,1,'sm')`.

Comment: Since $rank(B) = 250$ w. prob. 1, you can get the smallest positive singular value $s_{min}$ of $A$ with the command $d = svd(B); smin = d(250)^2.

Comment: @Hans: That's a good point. I assumed that it would be faster to [find the one smallest eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient_iteration) than to compute all 250 singular values, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain me on what principle code eigs(B'*B,1,'sm') works? Also, what is sm in this code? Thank you again.

Comment: @srijan: Please see [the documentation for `eigs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you for your patience and answer. I understood now it stands for smallest eigenvalues. May I ask you again in case I am having any other question related with this in future?

Comment: All I know about `eigs` is what is in the documentation, but if you have questions about the linear algebra in the rest of the answer feel free to ask.

Answer (score 4):

**Summary**

The answer is...use `svds`.

**What are the singular values?**

There may be some confusion over how you get the singular values. The command `svd` computes the singular values and the components that you don't want. The command `svds` only computes the singular values.

As explained here [Computing pinv](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75789/what-is-step-by-step-logic-of-pinv-pseudoinverse/2197696#2197696), the first step in computing the full singular value decomposition of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is to compute the eigenvalue spectrum of the product matrix $\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A}$.
$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\lambda\left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)}
$$
These are precisely the numbers you want (after they are ordered and $0$ values are culled). These values are returned by `svds`.

If you want to continue and compute the eigenvectors, and resolve the domain matrices, then execute `svd`.

**Background**

For background, the SVD is very powerful, and very expensive. You just want part of the information, and you hope to avoid the performance penalty. But the heart of the complexity of the SVD is the eigenvalue problem. This demands finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial. In your case, a polynomial of order 500. The task of finding roots to general polynomials is a demanding numeric problem. So by asking for the singular values, you have incurred most of the computational cost.

**Caution**

As an inside, make sure you understand how to handle small singular values. There is a tough issue of deciding if a small eigenvalue is a valid element of the spectrum, or a zero eigenvalue disguised as machine noise. Some discussion is [Number of Singular Values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426383/number-of-singular-values/2213922#2213922) and [Kernel mapping from feature space to input space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167586/kernel-mapping-from-feature-space-to-input-space/2207563#2207563).

It may be reasonable to change your requirement from finding the smallest eigenvalue to setting a threshold for smallest eigenvalue.

**Keep posting**

As your problem and understanding evolve, keep posting and keep the discussion going.

**@Rahul's answer**

User @Rahul has a better solution because he skips the unneeded step of forming the product matrix. Almost certainly, `eigs`, `svds`, and `svd` call the same routine to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial, and in this instance the time savings may be imperceptible. Failure to recognize that we can bypass the product matrix is a critical oversight.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer and pointing out many interesting points.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all answers/comments, I suggest a method based on @Rahul's method (which has converted the problem from SVD to EVD).

**Summary**

The solution in short: **`s = 1/eigs(inv(B'*B),1,'lm');`**

**Description**

There exist a [Power Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Numerical_computation_of_eigenvalues) for calculation of the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of matrix $M$. It is to compute a sequence of unit vectors:

$\frac{Mv}{||Mv||}$, $\frac{M^2v}{||M^2v||}$, ..., $\frac{M^kv}{||M^kv||}$

starting from an initial random vector $v$ which almost always converges to the eigenvector with largest eigenvalue of $M$.

If [Power Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Numerical_computation_of_eigenvalues) requires few iterations to converge and also calculating the inverse matrix $(B^tB)^{-1}$ requires relatively lower computations, then we can use it to compute eigenvector $v$ with largest eigenvalue of $(B^tB)^{-1}$ which is the eigenvector with smallest eigenvalue of $B^tB$. finally use the inverse of largest eignvalue of $(B^tB)^{-1}$.

Having the eigenvector $v$ its corresponding eigenvalue can be obtained using $Mv=\lambda v$ (i.e: with $M = B^tB$ eigenvalue of v is equal to all elements of vector $M*v ./ v$ hence with less calculations $M(1,:)*v / v(1)$).

I have conducted a comparison of results and running times of all above methods in MATLAB.

```
n = 100; 
t1 = 0; t2 = 0; t3 = 0; t4 = 0; t5 = 0; % for measuring running times

B = rand(500,250); 
A = B*B'; 
for i = 1:n,
 tic; svds = svd(A); s1 = min(svds(svds > 1e-6)); t1 = t1 + toc;   % @srijan
 tic; s3 = eigs(B'*B,1,'sm'); t2 = t2 + toc;                       % @Rahul
 tic; svds = svd(B); s2 = min(svds(svds > 1e-6))^2; t3 = t3 + toc; % @Hans Engler
 tic; s4 = 1/eigs(inv(B'*B),1,'lm'); t4 = t4 + toc;                % @Alireza Kazemi(*)
end; 
% Computed smallest non-zero signular value of A
[s1,s2, s3, s4]
%-> RESULT: 3.403670094444867  3.403670094444888  3.403670094444812  3.403670094444802
% average times
[t1/n , t2/n, t3/n, t4/n]
%-> RESULT: 0.1193    0.0410    0.0317    0.0202 (seconds)
% ration of average times to the initial question of @srijan
[t1/t1, t2/t1, t3/t1, t4/t1]
%-> RESULT: 1.0000    0.3436    0.2655    0.1693
```

It is clear that the proposed method is fastest among compared methods, even though it needs a matrix inversion.

I must also mention that I did not implemented the Power Method here but just guessed that Matlab $eigs(...,'lm')$ must have implemented it.